# Rails scope for ApplicationController methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

When I call a method which lives inside ApplicationController from an inheriting controller like UsersController < ApplicationController, what will be the scope of that method? ApplicationController or UsersController?

Let's say I have those files

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def method1
    method2
  end

  def method2
    ...
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # call method1 from here

  def method2
    ...
  end
end
```

So as you can see here, I call method1 (which lives inside appcontroller) from UsersController;
Will method1 call the method2 living inside UsersController or inside ApplicationController?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a running example: http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/4e396/2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The new class `UsersController` inherits all the methods from the original class `ApplicationController`.  When you `def` a new method in `UsersController`, then it replaces the definition from the parent controller, but any other methods are still in place, and are evaluated when they are called.

So, `UsersController#method1` will call `UsersController#method2`.  Any time a method is called, ruby searches from the current context up the stack until it finds a matching method:

1) it checks `UsersController#method1`, finds nothing

2) it checks `ApplicationController#method1`, and executes it, which calls `#method2`

3) it checks `UsersController#method2`, which is found, and executed.

Comment: A better explanation than mine.

Answer (score 1):

The method in the inheriting class (UserController) will override the method from the inherited class (ApplicationController).

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def method1
    method2 # => 'foo'
    method3 # => 'foobar'
  end

  def method2
    'foo'
  end

  def method3
    'foobar'
  end
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # call method1 from here

  def method1
    method2 # => 'bar'
    method3 # => 'foobar'
  end


  def method2
    'bar'
  end
end
```